# Replace occurrences of space in URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have a URL in an iPhone application to work with. But the problem is that it has some spaces in the URL. I want to replace the spaces with '%20'. I know that there are the `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` and `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` methods. I also have used them. But they are not working for me. The spaces are replaced by some unusual values.

I'm applying those methods on an instance of `NSString`.

Comment: Check out this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695911/question-about-character-of-nsstring-invalid-in-url-on-iphone The Answer: NSString* escapedUrl = [originalUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The correct format for replacing space from url is :

**Swift 4.2 , Swift 5**

```
var urlString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

**Swift 4**

```
var urlString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

**Objective C**

```
NSString *urlString;//your url string.

urlString = [originalUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

or

```
urlString = [originalUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

iOS 9 and later

```
urlString = [originalUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: @RaquibulIslam I edited my answer , please check now

Comment: I think stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding() is deprecated. Instead, we can use stringByRemovingPercentEncoding

Comment: will it work for local path? i mean for documents dir

Comment: @guru I don't think you need to format path for local document dir

Comment: If you use this funcion in a URL that is already encoded, it will not work. Must be carefull.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 2.0**

```
let originalUrl = "http://myurl.com/my photo.png"
let urlNew:String = urlReq.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters( NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

**Output:**

```
http://myurl.com/my%20photo.png
```

Answer (score 6):

To replace occurence in **SWIFT 3** :

```
let updatedUrl = originalUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: will it work for local path? i mean for documents dir

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

Another way to replace an empty space with replacingOccurrences method:

```
let yourString = "http://myurl.com/my photo.png"
let urlNew:String = yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20").trimmed
```

That will replace the empty space (" ") with '%20'

Comment: error : Value of type 'String' has no member 'trim'

Comment: @Mehdico that is odd, I always trim my strings. At this example you don’t have to trim the string since you know what it is. But I’d clean the project and try to run it again. at the end of the string add *.trimmed*

Comment: dude i think you use an extension for String class, because .trimmed is not found in swift 4 and 4.2

Comment: You don’t have to trim the string in order to replace white space

Comment: Try this for encoding :-  stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: URLPathAllowedCharacterSet and  for decoding  :-                               [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.yourString stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]]

Comment: will it work for local path? i mean for documents dir

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
var urlString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: will it work for local path? i mean for documents dir

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution: just use the stringy method...

.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

...at the end of your string, and it will do as it says.

Apple should be EMBARRASSED that their URL(string: ) method doesn't automatically do this (and more).  It's 2023 and I wasted 3 hours finding this half-assed solution.

My specific example was inside cellForItemAt and having to do with optionals.

```
let stringOfImageURLFromFirebase = wordController?.word?.images[indexPath.item].imgUrl

let stringWithNoSpaces = string?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

if let imageURLString = stringWithNoSpaces,
   let imageURL = URL(string: imageURLString) {
         cell.definitionImageView.loadImageFromFirebase(url: imageURL)
    } else {
        cell.definitionImageView.image = UIImage(named: "slictionarylogo")
    }
```

You can fuddle with .addingPercentEncoding for a long time, try NSURL nonsense, and you'll just be faster with using the obvious.  Apple sucks, and should've made this painfully easy since it's such a common problem.  Again, they are asleep at the wheel, and their documentation is AWFUL too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlString :String = originalUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
```

Comment: You need to give more of an explanation to this code. There are others coming to this question looking for understanding not just code. Help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
let url = "https:youtube.56432fgrtxcvfname=xyz&sname=tuv"
let urlNew:String = url.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
Alamofire.request(urlNew, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON{
response in
print(response)    
}
```

It will remove all kind of spaces from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.3, clear space your string,

```
let str = "  www.test.com  "
let trimmed = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(str) // "www.test.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

**SWIFT 3.1**

Simple way to replace an empty space with replacingOccurrences:

```
URL = URL.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Comment: Doesn't work as URL has no member 'replacingOccurences'. String has that method but URL doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4, iOS-9

```
let **urlSearchVal**:String = "top 10 movies"     
let urlString = 

    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=\(urlSearchVal)&key=......&type=video"   
//replace ...... above with your youtube key   
// to ignoring white space in search  
        let UrlString :String = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please improve the quality of you answer

Answer (score -1):

A Swift 4 solution.  You simply pass through a string and it fills spaces with %20 and adds "http://" to the beginning to the string.  Pretty sweet!

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: String)
```